# Sub-setting with multiple text files using a loop

Tags: r

I have many identical text files with 3 columns and 141 rows of data, tab separated. I want to read them all into r using a loop, but I only want to read the second column (and preferably only rows 49:141). I can't get the code to work for only reading in 1 column, but it will work without the sub-setting and will read the whole file. It reads each file as a separate data frame. Seems the usual notation for sub-setting doesn't apply when doing loops, because each file is a separate data frame.

With the code below I get the error: Error in TEST2[49:141, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions.

```
files<-list.files()
TEST2 <- lapply(files[49:141, 2], function(fn)read.table(fn,header=FALSE, sep="", fill = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`files` is the object you want to iterate over. You can't use indexing in the way you tried. Rather try something like this:

```
files <- list.files()

my_read_function <- function(x) {
  data <- read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep="", fill = TRUE)
  return(data[49:141, 2])
}

lapply(files, my_read_function)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked first time. I'm not going to pretend I understand how it worked, but thanks for trying to explain :-).